# How to read InputStream twice if I am using ReadableByteChannel and BufferedReader?

Tags: java

How to read an `InputStream` twice if I am using `ReadableByteChannel` and `BufferedReader`?

Here is my code:

```java
ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(input);
WritableByteChannel outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(output);

InputStream ind = Channels.newInputStream(inputChannel);
ReadableByteChannel inputChannel1 = Channels.newChannel(ind);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(ind, baos);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(10240);
long size = 0;
while (inputChannel1.read(buffer) != -1) {
    buffer.flip();
    size += outputChannel.write(buffer);
    buffer.clear();
}

byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bais));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer bufferResponse = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    bufferResponse.append(inputLine);
}
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(bufferResponse.toString());
```

Comment: You know you can just do `JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(new String(bytes));`? Not quite clear what you want to read *again* but 'bytes' is of course still in memory and usable

Answer (score 1):

You've written a lot of code to copy `input` to two destinations: `output` and `jsonResponse`. As you have made an in-memory copy of `input` => `bytes` there is no need to scan `input` twice, and you don't need to use `IOUtils` for a simple copy to byte[] which you can re-use to send to the two destinations:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
input.transferTo(baos);
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
output.write(bytes);
```

Then do as @g00se suggests - if the char encoding is platform default:

```
String s = new String(bytes /*, or insert another charset here */);
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(s);
```

You should also deal with closing the input/output streams, best done with try-with-resources block.